# TWA android border top navigation

Tags: android, twa

[image: I have this line here]

how I can to remove this line?

I use this project https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa

Answer (score 1):

That is the the navigation bar divided and you can control its colour.

### Using Bubblewrap

When using [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/) (recommended), you can change the colour by updating the `navigationDividerColor` and `navigationDividerColorDar` in `twa-manifest.json`.

### In AndroidManifest.xml

When building the application yourself and using the default LauncherActivity, you can get setting the correct meta-tags as part of the Activity definition in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="androix.browser.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_DIVIDER_COLOR" 
    android:resource="@color/navigationDividerColor" />

<meta-data 
    android:name="androix.browser.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_DIVIDER_COLOR_DARK"
    android:resource="@color/navigationDividerColorDark" />
```

PS: the https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa demo has been deprecated.